# Loop through different tables for count

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, stored-procedures

I have a table that has thousands of records. Usually 100k-200k records. There is a field in this table (MATCH_ID). I have to get count of this ID from 100 different tables whose field(TABLE_ID) value matches with MATCH_ID.

I think implementing this using cursors would be a bad idea here. How can I achieve this with better performance.

Comment: There's no way this should be tagged both mysql and ms sql server.

Comment: I have editted it..thanks.

Comment: Thanks for updating. Any chance at changing the database design? It's possible with dynamic sql or cursors, but the performance will be bad.

Comment: So you want a count of those matching MATCH_ID per table?

Comment: I need to get the total count of MATCH_ID from 100 tables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes a couple of a couple of assumptions, but you could create a dynamic `UNION ALL` query; which'll be far faster than a `CURSOR`:

```
DECLARE @MatchID int; --Guessed data type; will need a value

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = STUFF((SELECT @CRLF +
                         N'UNION ALL' + @CRLF +
                         N'SELECT N' + QUOTENAME(s.[name],'''') + N' AS SchemaName,' + @CRLF +
                         N'       N' + QUOTENAME(t.[name],'''') + N' AS TableName,' + @CRLF +
                         N'       COUNT(*) AS RowCount' + @CRLF +
                         N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.[name]) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.[name]) + @CRLF +
                         N'WHERE MATCH_ID = @MatchID'
                  FROM sys.schemas s
                       JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
                       JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
                  WHERE c.[name] = N'MATCH_ID'
                  ORDER BY t.[name]
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,13,N'') + N';';

--SELECT @SQL; --Your best friend

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@MatchID int', @MatchID;
```

As I can't test this, use your "best friend" if you get any syntax errors, or you don't quite get the results you expect.